# CSS box-shadow on submenu hover

Tags: wordpress, css, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS override for my Wordpress child-theme, where I can't get my head around how to get the box-shadow to keep showing when on hover.

```
.menu {
    background-color: #8a8a8a;
    background-image: none;
    clear: both;
    filter: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-nav {
    clear: both;
}

.menu,
.menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.menu li:hover {
    white-space: normal;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.menu li li {
    float: none;
}

.menu ul {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    top: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu li li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.menu:after,
.menu ul:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.menu,
.menu ul {
    min-height: 0;
}

.menu ul,
.menu ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a:hover,
.menu li li a:hover {
     color: #00ACA1;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
     margin-top: 1px;
     min-width: 15em;
     width: auto;
}

.menu a {
     border-left: none;
     color: #ffffff;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: block;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 700;
     height: 35px;
     line-height: 35px;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 0.9em;
     position: relative;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-shadow: none;
     white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu a:hover {
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     background-image: none;
     color: #00ACA1;
     filter: none;
}

ul.menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #00ACA1;
}

.menu .current_page_item a,
.menu .current-menu-item a {
     background-color: #ffffff;
     color: #00ACA1;
}

.front-page .menu .current_page_item a {
     background-color: ffffff;
     background-image: none;
     filter: none;
     color: #00ACA1;
}

.menu li li {
     background: #ffffff;
     background-image: none;
     border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
     color: #00ACA1;
     filter: none;
     margin: -1px 0 1px 0;
     width: auto;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #8a8a8a;
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #8a8a8a;
     box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #8a8a8a;
}

.menu li li a {
     background: transparent !important;
     border: none;
     color: #00ACA1;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 400;
     height: auto;
     height: 20px;
     line-height: 20px;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     text-shadow: none;
     white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu li:hover > a{
    color:#00ACA1;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.menu li li a:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1 !important;
    color: #00ACA1; !important;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0;
    filter: none;
}

.menu li li:hover  {
    background: #f1f1f1 !important;
    filter: none;
    -box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

.menu ul > li + li {
    border-top: 0;
}

.menu li li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.menu > li:first-child > a {
    border-left: none;
}

.menu a#responsive_menu_button {
    display: none;
}

.main-nav #responsive_current_menu_item {
     display: none;
}

/*.js .main-nav .menu {*/
/*display: block;*/
/*}*/
```

Thanks for any advice! I'm a complete noob, so I've just edited the code from the core css from the main wordpress theme  (Responsive)

Comment: If you're in Chrome use developer tools to inspect the element and to style it with F12, Firefox has that opetion too, but you can download Firebug, Opera has that as well, and to my knowledge IE as well. Always use those, that way you can easily influence your elements on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dingo_d! That helped me out! I found how to get the effect I was looking for by adding box-shadow to:

```
.menu li:hover > ul {
    top: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #8a8a8a;
}

.menu li li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #8a8a8a;
}
```